# How do we answer to offensive phrases like 你 妈 bi?

Tags: slang

I am studying Chinese and I heard the phrase 'ni ma bi' from a native teenager. I am sure that it's an offensive phrase but I would appreciate your help.

How we could answer to such a phrase in Chinese?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you! I think what you have suggest is more proper. Though i was ready to say something like' 你不要在我前面拍马屁'  (i found it searching phrases in the internet)

Comment: Firstly you say "I am sure it is an offensive phrase" -- you are correct, but do you know what it means? What would an equivalent be in English or any other language? 

Now, knowing what it actually means, what is your desired response? Do you wish to just shrug it off and get on with your life, or do you wish to engage in a verbal battle of pejoratives with a teenager? Knowing the desired response is key to helping you figure out what you should (or shouldn't) say in response.

Answer (score 3):

It is not wise to reply to any offensive words. Keep the blame to himself. Don't get involved.

Answer (score 2):

你瞅你那个作(zuō)死的样子.

I don't know how to translate, I use this get a friend.

That day, a new one came to us, and there was a fellow that we both know each other very well, that fellow want to show himself to the new one, so he made a bad joke with me, and laughed out loudly.

I was waiting for his laugh, and said " XX(his nickname), 你瞅你那个作死的样子". That fellow turned out a balloon without air.

Comment: 你瞅你那个作(zuō)死的样子: My attempt at a more or less word-for-word translation is:
"you look at your this manner of making trouble" ; 
a translation could be "(wow) check it out, you're really looking for trouble"

Answer (score 1):

I think whatever words he says to you，you can always repeat his words with a louder voice and stronger momentum. That is a simple way，but it must lead to fight.

Comment: But remember, why  don't care? The OP and the other person are probably having  a argument/

Answer (score 1):

A native speaker could use:

"你嘴巴放干净点" (You'd better watch your manner)

"嘴巴别太臭。" (similar to the one above but milder)

“你他妈再说一遍？” (say that again, I dare you.)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to copycat whatever he / she says.